# Deriving the unknowns for a Gaussian Quadrature rule so that it would be exact for polynomials of degree as high as possible

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The goal is to find the unknowns that would satisfy the Gaussian Quadrature rule for

$ \int_{-1}^1 f(x) x^2 dx \approx af(-d) + bf(0) + cf(d)$

such that the rule would be exact for polynomials of degree as high as possible. Which seems simple enough. There are 4 unknowns, so this rule should be exact for $f(x) = 1, x, x^2, x^3$. This yields a system of 4 equations with 4 unknowns.

Replacing in the above for the different $f(x)$, we get:

$
 \frac{2}{3} = a + b + c \\
  0 = -ad + cd\\
  \frac{2}{5} = ad^2 + cd^2 \\
  0 = -ad^3 + cd^3
$

When I plugged this into Wolfram Alpha it didn't seem to produce a solution.

My question is: can the Gaussian Quadrature rule be exact for polynomials of degree greater than the degrees of freedom in this situation? If I add in $f(x) = x^4$ there would be a solution - so it would be exact for polynomials up to degree 4, right? Otherwise, what is going wrong here?

edit: I redid it, why do I get the correct solution when I expect the rule to be exact for $f(x) = 1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5$? The comment below hinted at the fact that we should expect exact results for polynomials of up to degree 5.

So I went back in my notes and used a theorem that said for the Gaussian Quadrature rule $I = \sum_{i=0}^n w_i f(x_i)$, any polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2n + 1$ would produce the exact result. Is that correct?

Comment: There are really 6 parameters: 3 nodes and 3 weights, and hence you might expect it to be exact for polynomials up to degree 5. The problem made the assumption that the nodes are symmetric around 0.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The middle term has $f(0)$ already given to me, would it be 5 parameters then?

In my notes, a theorem says that the highest degree of polynomials that are expected to be exact is $2n + 1$. If I consider the nodes $x_0, x_1, x_2$ in this problem then I could take $n=2$ and get degree of 5 as well. Is that another way of thinking of it?

Comment: For an approximation $w_0f(x_0) + w_1f(x_1) + w_2f(x_2)$ there are 6 parameters: $w_0, w_1, w_2, x_0, x_1, x_2$. So intuitively, the approximation can be made exact for $1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5$, since that requires solving 6 equations. In the problem, it was assumed that $x_0 = x_2$ and $x_1 = 0$, which is a simplifying assumption/guess made based on prior knowledge of the solution.

Comment: I see, that makes sense now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using $1,x,x^2,x^3$ as a basis, it's slightly better to use the orthogonal polynomials over $[-1,1]$ generated by the weighting function $w(x)=x^2$.  These polynomials can be iteratively generated by the Gram-Schmidt procedure
$$
p_n(x) = x^2 - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{\langle x^n, p_i\rangle}{\langle p_i,p_i\rangle}
$$
where the inner product is defined as
$$
\langle a, b\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 a(x)b(x)x^2dx.
$$
This results in the polynomials
$$
p_0(x)=1\\
p_1(x) = x\\
p_2(x) = x^2 - \frac{3}{5}\\
p_3(x) = x^3 - \frac{5}{7}x.
$$
The abscissa are chosen to be the roots of $p_3(x)$, which are $x_i \in [ -\sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}, 0,\sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}]$.

To find the weights, enforce
$$
\int_{-1}^1 p_n(x)x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3}\delta_{n,0}.
$$
Since the orthogonal polynomials span all polynomials, this is equivalent to your equations for the standard basis.

Discretizing these integrals lead to the equations that solve for the weights
$$
\sum_{i=0}^2 w_i p_n(x_i)=\frac{2}{3}\delta_{n,0},
$$
which can be written as a matrix equation
$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-\sqrt{\frac{5}{7}} & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{5}{7}} \\
\frac{4}{35} & -\frac{3}{5} & \frac{4}{35}
\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{c} w_0 \\ w_1 \\ w_2 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{2}{3} \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
which has solution $w_i\in\left[\frac{7}{25},\frac{8}{75},\frac{7}{25}  ​\right]$.

The reason Gaussian quadrature methods have a high degree of exactness is the way the abscissa are chosen.  Suppose you have a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $2N-1$. It can be (polynomially) divided by $p_n(x)$ with result
$$
f(x) = p_n(x)q(x) + r(x)
$$
where the quotient polynomial $q(x)$ and remainder $r(x)$ are of degree $N-1$ or less.  When performing the quadrature method
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x)x^2dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} w_i p_n(x_i)q(x_i)  + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} w_i r(x_i),
$$
The first term vanishes and the second term is exact.